# Consuming REST API using JSON with Grails

Tags: rest, grails

I'm trying to consume a REST service that requires me to supply login details in JSON:

```
def resp = new RestBuilder().put("https://..."){        
   contentType "application/json"
   accept "application/json"
   header "X-ESA-API-Key", "ROBOT"
   json {
      type = "STANDARD_LOGIN"
      login = "username"
      password = "password"
   }
}
```

This results in the service responding “Method not allowed”.

However, using cURL:

```
$ curl --compressed \
-X POST \
-d '{"type":"STANDARD_LOGIN","login":"username","password":"password"}' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'X-ESA-API-Key: ROBOT' \
'https://...
```

I get a proper response and authentication from the service.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong in Grails or how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference is that `PUT` is used in `RestBuilder` whereas `POST` in `curl`.

`PUT` "Method not allowed". Use `post()` instead.

Comment: This is what happens when you write code after midnigth. And I've been looking at this for an hour. Shame ...